# How to make a pmf of a random variable that does not have a finite expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been racking my head and searching everywhere, but i don't get how to make a pmf of a random variable that does not have a finite expectation.

Sorry if it's been asked before, but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{-2}I(x > 1)$. Note that $\int_{1}^{\infty}{x^{-2}dx}= -x^{-1}\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}=1$. Therefore, $f$ is a density. Now, if $X$ follows density $f$, then $E[X]=\int_{1}^{\infty}{x \cdot x^{-2}dx} = \log(x)\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}=\infty$.

Comment: The main argument for several question such as the one you asked relies on observing that $x^{-(1+\epsilon)}$ goes quickly enough to $0$ so that $x^{-(1+\epsilon)}$ has finite integral but the integral of $x^{-1}$ is infinite. For example, now you can find a random variable that has finite mean but infinite variance.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does the ∣∞ 1 (don't know how to type it either) mean?

Comment: It means that you are integrating from $1$ to $\infty$. That is, $\log(x)\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}=\log(\infty)-\log(1)$.

Comment: how is it different from ∫∞1 then?

Comment: Do you know how to solve integrals? For example, how would you solve $\int_{1}^{\infty}{x^{-2}dx}$?

Comment: This i would solve it by integrating it getting 1/x+c, and then insert ∞ on x' place, and minus it with 1 on x' place, so 1/∞-1/1=1, or am i wrong?

Comment: You are right! $-x^{-1}\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}$ means precisely $-\infty^{-1}-(-1^{-1})$, just like what you wrote.

Comment: but what's the difference between ∫∞1 and ∣∞1 except placement? also what do u call ∣ in latex for example?

Comment: ooooooh wait nvm i see now, i would still love the name of the ∣ in latex though, or just the name of it's called in general :)

Comment: The latex is \bigg|_{1}^{\infty}

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac {2}{\pi} \frac 1{1+x^2} & x\ge 0\\0&x<0\end{cases}$

Comment: How is pi suddenly involved?

Comment: A frequency distribution must be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx  =1$ whereas  $\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1{1+x^2} dx = \frac {\pi}2$ hence the $\frac 2\pi$ factor.